# Removing unnecessary whitespace in a J2EE/Struts Application in WebSphere

Tags: struts, websphere, jstl, whitespace

Is anyone familiar with a technique for removal of whitespace that results from the use of tag libraries such as JSTL?  I know that you can do this [in Tomcat via a `trimSpaces` initialization parameter](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=556549), but does anyone have similar experience doing this type of thing within WebSphere App Server?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Increase html source readability or reduce html page size?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using version 2.1 or later of the JSP spec, you can simply include the following directive in your JSP, which will strip out whitespace before sending the resultant payload over the wire:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/trim_spaces_in_your_jsp1